# C asm jmp going back to jmp after performing the jmp

Tags: c, assembly

I'm performing a relative jump in some `asm` code in `C`. I've got the jump working as intended, but it goes back to right after the jump happens and finished running the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function() {
    asm("jmp .+0x31"); //this happens to be where I want to jump to from the function call
}

void main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int x;
    x = 0;
    function();
    x = 1;
    x = x + 1;
    printf("%d\n", x);
}

0x000000000040053f <+0>:     push   %rbp
0x0000000000400540 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x0000000000400543 <+4>:     sub    $0x20,%rsp
0x0000000000400547 <+8>:     mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
0x000000000040054a <+11>:    mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
0x000000000040054e <+15>:    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
0x0000000000400555 <+22>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
0x000000000040055a <+27>:    callq  0x400536 <function>
0x000000000040055f <+32>:    movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
0x0000000000400566 <+39>:    addl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
0x000000000040056a <+43>:    mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
0x000000000040056d <+46>:    mov    %eax,%esi
0x000000000040056f <+48>:    mov    $0x400620,%edi
0x0000000000400574 <+53>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
0x0000000000400579 <+58>:    callq  0x400410 <printf@plt>
0x000000000040057e <+63>:    nop
0x000000000040057f <+64>:    leaveq
0x0000000000400580 <+65>:    retq
```

Following the call of `function()`, it prints a 0 as intended, but it then goes back through the code after `function()` is called and prints 2 as well. Am I missing how `jmp` works? Is there a way to exit via `asm` code?

The goal of this is to skip

```
x = 1;
x = x + 1;
```

and just print 0, then exit the file.

Comment: Can you provide a disassembly of the compiled code? Also, have you tried stepping through your program in an assembly-level debugger, such as gdb? Either of those things should give you the answer. And if you're not doing any of those things, how do you know what offset to jump to, considering it could change at any time?

Comment: Take a look at the generated code, and where your function and the jump instruction is in relation to where you really want to jump. And do note that the location might change without warning, depending on compiler, compiler version and even which flags you pass to the compiler.

Comment: Looks like willfully breaking your code. What do you intend with this code? Where do you think the jump goes to? What actually is at that location? Why do you think you should wirte such code?

Comment: @Olaf It's an exercise in learning how to work around `C` code by using `asm` instead.

Comment: @Satirez: If you learn Assembly, write Assembly source code files and don't mix it with C code! Inline-Assembly is hardly avoiding C code, but meant to insert small assembly language stubs into C functions. These stubs have to comply with the C ABI of the platform to not crash the program code as your code apparently does. Note: There is little to no use analysing the machine code, as that can (and likely will) change with modifications you make to the source code, compiler optimisations, compiler versions, etc.

Comment: @Olaf I don't have much choice in my language decisions unfortunately. The code doesn't crash exactly. It runs, but not as intended.

Comment: I don't hold students responsible for their instructors' weird requirements, but making relative jmps out of a function call is a stunningly bad idea. 1) When a function is `call`ed, things get pushed on the stack.  In the normal course of events, this data is popped off the stack by the matching `ret` statement at function's end. So this kind of jmp leaves the stack in a bad state. 2) Doing a relative jump assumes you know where you are jumping to relative to where you are. But the position of code is not guaranteed from compile to compile. What is the assignment's exact requirement here?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd The exact requirement is to have the `printf` statement print out 0 instead of 2. By doing the jump that I've been doing, it causes a 0 to be printed, but it continues back through the program printing 2 regardless.

Comment: Maybe rather than a JMP the professor wants you to modify the return address placed on the stack when `function` was called with the return address of the instruction you really want to return to (rather than the one right after the call)

Comment: Guessing that the code for `function` has traditional stack frame (pushing RBP and moving RSP to RBP.) then the return address is at 8(%RSP) You can add 11 (0x40056a - 40055f)  to that return address to get the point where 0 is moved to _EAX_ (`mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax`). So `function` could use a line like `asm("addq $11, 8(%rsp)");` . Should probably print 0. But as others have mentioned doing this is fraught with pitfalls

Comment: If the professor requires you to use a _JMP_ you can but you have to restore _RBP_ manually, skip over the return address, and then JMP to the relative offset. Something like `asm("pop %rbp; add $8, %rsp; jmp .+offset");`  `offset` has to be replaced with the appropriate value. That has the effect of restoring _RBP_ and getting that value off the stack, `add $8, %rsp` then rids you of the return address.

Comment: If it helps, inline assembler tutorial show how to do this by basically emulating goto statements.  You can even make it ABI compatible if you get the flags correct to the inline assembler setup.

Answer (score 2):

Since `function` doesn't execute a `ret` instruction, its return address is still there on the stack. That is, when `main` executes *its* `ret`, the return address it uses is in fact an address left by `function`, and lands back at `x = 1;` line.

To achieve your goal, `function` before doing a jump must adjust the stack pointer as if it has never been called.

That said, *don't try this at home*.

Comment: More like "try this at home *only*, for experimentation".  Don't ever use this in code that will be part of a real program that anyone will use for anything, because it will break as soon as you enable optimizations, or use a different compiler version that generates even slightly different asm.